# How do I map Features against their Feature importance in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot feature importances for a `DecisionTreeRegressor` and map each feature importance back to the column name. Anyone could advise on how I can do that? Thank you in advance.
This is the code I'm using:

```
df1=df[['CRIM' 'ZN' 'INDUS' 'CHAS' 'NOX' 'RM' 'AGE' 'DIS' 'RAD' 'TAX' 'PTRATIO','LSTAT' ]] 

x=df1[['CRIM' 'ZN' 'INDUS' 'CHAS' 'NOX' 'RM' 'AGE' 'DIS' 'RAD' 'TAX' 'PTRATIO']]
y=df1['LSTAT']
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm_model=LinearRegression()
lm_model.fit (x,y)
#y_pred=lm_model.predict(y)

# fit the model
model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

yhat = model.predict(x_test)
# evaluate predictions
from sklearn.metrics import  mean_absolute_error
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, yhat)
print('MAE: %.3f' % mae)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
# fit the model
model.fit(x, y)
# get importance
importance = model.feature_importances_
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
# plot feature importance
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: It will probably help if you edit the question so show a couple rows of `importance`, and explain in more detail what you mean by "map" importance back to column name.  Do you want the column name in a dataframe next to importance?  Do you want column name showing up in a plot, or what?

Comment: It would still helpful to include some sample data. You mention a DataFrame and column, but neither of these seem to appear in your provided code snippet (you've also not tagged a DataFrame library). Generally speaking it is helpful to have a small program from `import` to `show()` which can be copied into a clean workspace and run.

Comment: Are you trying to map the Importance against the Features?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to create a DataFrame comprising of Features and their Importances

```
data = list(zip(df.columns, model.feature_importances_))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Feature', 'Importance'])
```

Comment: Upvote and Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (Helps the SO Community)